# Unrecognized jedec id

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, spi

On linux 2.6.25 i have output:

```
physmap platform flash device: 00800000 at ff800000
physmap-flash.0: Found 1 x16 devices at 0x0 in 8-bit bank
 Amd/Fujitsu Extended Query Table at 0x0040
physmap-flash.0: CFI does not contain boot bank location. Assuming top.
number of CFI chips: 1
cfi_cmdset_0002: Disabling erase-suspend-program due to code brokenness.
RedBoot partition parsing not available
Using physmap partition information
Creating 6 MTD partitions on "physmap-flash.0":
0x00000000-0x00040000 : "U-Boot image"
0x00040000-0x00050000 : "U-Boot params"
0x00050000-0x00250000 : "Linux kernel"
0x00250000-0x00750000 : "RFS"
0x00750000-0x007f0000 : "JFFS"
0x007f0000-0x00800000 : "unused"
m25p80 spi1.0: s70fl256p (16384 Kbytes)
Creating 2 MTD partitions on "tpts1691.spi.flash":
0x00000000-0x00400000 : "spi_flash_part0"
0x00400000-0x01000000 : "spi_flash_part1"
DSPI: Coldfire master initialized
```

And i try to port spi flash driver to new kernel 4.12.5.
I add in spi_nor_ids in spi-nor/spi-nor.c my jedecid

```
{ "s70fl256p",  INFO(0x012018,      0, 256 * 1024,  64, 0) },
```

but i have error:

**spi_coldfire spi_coldfire: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
m25p80 spi1.0: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: 00, 00, 00**

in output:

```
physmap platform flash device: 00800000 at ff800000
physmap-flash.0: Found 1 x16 devices at 0x0 in 8-bit bank. Manufacturer ID 0x000001 Chip ID 0x000201
Amd/Fujitsu Extended Query Table at 0x0040
  Amd/Fujitsu Extended Query version 1.3.
physmap-flash.0: CFI contains unrecognised boot bank location (1). Assuming bottom.
number of CFI chips: 1
Creating 6 MTD partitions on "physmap-flash.0":
0x000000000000-0x000000040000 : "U-Boot image"
0x000000040000-0x000000050000 : "U-Boot params"
0x000000050000-0x000000250000 : "Linux kernel"
0x000000250000-0x000000750000 : "RFS"
0x000000750000-0x0000007f0000 : "JFFS"
0x0000007f0000-0x000000800000 : "unused"
uclinux[mtd]: probe address=0x3549d0 size=0x10804000
Creating 1 MTD partitions on "ram":
0x000000000000-0x000010804000 : "ROMfs"
spi_coldfire spi_coldfire: master is unqueued, this is deprecated
m25p80 spi1.0: unrecognized JEDEC id bytes: 00, 00, 00
DSPI: Coldfire master initialized
```

Maybe someone has already solved this error's?
Thank you.

Comment: Wait, are you sure there is no driver in mainline already?

Comment: Yes, it is specific driver.

Comment: Are you **sure**? From the output I see only standard drivers which are long time ago went to upstream.

Comment: Moreover, in the first you have *Assuming top*, while second shows *Assuming bottom*.

Comment: Yes, i port specific spi driver for mcf5474 and there is no driver for it in mainline.

Comment: So, you are trying to a) implement an SPI **host** controller driver, *and* b) the one which is called DMA SPI? If so, have you checked one under *drivers/spi/spi-fsl-dspi.c*? http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/spi/spi-fsl-dspi.c

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand,can you explain what i need to check?

Comment: Compile the kernel with driver either builtin or a module. Be sure that your Device Tree source *or* platform code refers to this driver with properly set up properties (addresses, etc).

Comment: Are you sure your SPI driver is working correctly? Reading a flash ID of "00, 00, 00" suggests that it may not be successfully reading data from the device at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st message `spi_coldfire: master is unqueued, this is deprecated` is not an error.
This just a warning that the registering SPI controller has its own message transfer callback `master->transfer`. It is deprecated but still supported in `kernel 4.12.5`.
Look at `drivers/spi/spi.c:1993`.

The 2nd message: I suspect, that your flash doesn't have JEDEC ID at all (reads 0,0,0), but your flash_info has. So to avoid calling `spi_nor_read_id()` just let `info->id_len` to be `0`. `id_len` calculates as `.id_len = (!(_jedec_id) ? 0 : (3 + ((_ext_id) ? 2 : 0)))`, so the possible solution is simply to let `jedec_id` be `0`.
Like:

```
{ "s70fl256p",  INFO(0,      0, 256 * 1024,  64, 0) },
```

Comment: Thank you. I will tru today to fix it. But you wrote  The 2nd message: I suspect, that your flash doesn't have JEDEC ID at all (reads 0,0,0). In linux 2.6.25 i have correct output m25p80 spi1.0: s70fl256p (16384 Kbytes).

Comment: Thinking on the way home, I realized there could be another scenario. spi_nor_match_id() succeed. But as your jedec id is != 0, so your info->id_len > 0 too and the spi_nor_read_id() calls at 1567 line of spi-nor.c. The way to avoid calling this function is to make (name && info->id_len) clause false, then just to let jedec id = 0 like
{ "s70fl256p",  INFO(0,      0, 256 * 1024,  64, 0) },

Comment: I fix it: 1. I need to sset my jedec id to zero and add to my flash_platform_data structure to type field my device chip because, in m25p80.c in m25_probe you can read:

For some (historical?) reason many platforms provide two different
names in flash_platform_data: "name" and "type". Quite often name isset to "m25p80" and then "type" provides a real chip name.
         * If that's the case, respect "type" and ignore a "name".

Comment: Glad to hear that! I fixed my answer and if it looks correct for you, could you please mark it :)